Why did Tess dress in such a way to visit Letty?
In Fast X (2023), Letty pays a visit to Tess at an undisclosed location in costly costumes,
and Tess reacts to them:

Tess: Fancy coat. Expensive earrings.

Tess directs her attention to the spiky footwear that Letty is wearing and
reacts to it:

Tess: Those got to hurt. You really brought out the big guns, huh?

Why did Tess dress in such a way to visit Letty?
